# python3 how read csv, calc numbers and write to csv?

Tags: python-3.x

I have this sample.csv file

```
Germany,1,5,10,20
UK,0,2,4,10
Hungary,6,11,22,44
France,8,22,33,55
```

I would like to read data to 2D array, make some calculation with some numbers a and write new data to another csv file

I have this script

```
import csv
datafile = open('sample.csv', 'r')
datareader = csv.reader(datafile, delimiter=',')

with open('test_write.csv', 'wb') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)

data = []
for row in datareader:
    data.append(row)
print (data)

writer.writerows(data)
```

When I run script, I got this error related to write data

```
python3 read4.py 
[['Germany', '1', '5', '10', '20'], ['UK', '0', '2', '4', '10'], ['Hungary', '6', '11', '22', '44'], ['France', '8', '22', '33', '55']]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "read4.py", line 15, in <module>
    writer.writerows(data)
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

Another issue is when I tried to make numeric calculation with some field number

```
print ((data[1][3])+10)

  print ((data[1][3])+10)
TypeError: must be str, not int

Any idea please ?
```

Comment: Can you explain why you are using `'wb'` to write a csv?

Comment: OK, replaced write code to :

with open('test_write.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=' ',quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)

and I got this error :

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "read5.py", line 17, in <module>
    writer.writerows(data)
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.

Comment: That is correct behavior. Refresh on how `with open ...` works – the whole basic idea indeed is that the file automatically closes as soon as you leave the indented scope. Working as designed here, so to speak.